# FragmentManager replace() appears to duplicate cards in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragmentmanager

I'm new to posting in stack overflow and to android programming, so please forgive any mistakes I've made.

In my main activity, I have a navigation drawer in which utilizes the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected function, and displayed is the code within it:

```
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment myFragment = null;
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
            myFragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            //myFragment = new TestFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            // TODO: Add more
            break;

    }
    if(myFragment!=null)
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, myFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

What should be noted is that, when I attempt to select the button which calls for the HomeFragment, the application instead adds on the cards, instead of replacing it. The following code is HomeFragment.java

```
package tk.easthigh.witsmobile;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    SimpleRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview);

        final Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new SimpleRecyclerAdapter(context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new SimpleRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
               switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Hi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;

                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Undefined Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
}
```

The reference to the SimpleAdapter is the code located at this [github](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop/blob/master/MaterialSample/app/src/main/java/com/suleiman/material/adapter/SimpleRecyclerAdapter.java).
Here is activity_main.xml, which contains the FrameLayout with the id "nav_contentframe":

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_contentframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

Here is fragment_home.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="tk.easthigh.witsmobile.HomeFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

I was able to isolate that calling the replace method from the FragmentManager would appear to add on a copy of all the cards within the HomeFragment's RecyclerView.

For example, the RecyclerView has 4 cards. However, pressing the button on the nav drawer which should replace the content, instead duplicates the cards, leaving 8 cards as the end product. Pressing it again results in 12 cards, and so forth. Naturally, this is not the intended case, but after google for a couple of hours, and trying to debug, I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: My guess is you're just populating the adapter in `onStart` or `onResume` of your Fragment. `replace` doesn't necessarily destroy or delete a Fragment, so your `HomeFragment` isn't going to be rebuilt with an `onCreate` call.  So whenever you go back to your home fragment you add new elements to your adapter rather than replacing them.

Comment: @DeeV I believe that the adapter is being population on the `onCreateView` call, as the only reference of the adapter within the fragment is within the `onCreateView` method. I looked at the Documentation: it says that the replace method calls the `remove(Fragment)` method for all fragments within the container, and adds the fragment specified in the parameters of the replace method? Could you explain what you meant by "replace doesn't necessarily destroy or delete a Fragment"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong. Looking at the code in more detail, I noticed that in the `SimpleRecyclerAdapter` method is populated by two static `Lists` which are populated in the constructor of the `SimpleRecyclerAdapter`.  This means that every time a new `HomeFragment` is created, it will create a new `SimpleRecyclerAdapter` which will populate the same static Lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, the `SimpleRecyclerAdapter` references two static lists:

```
public static List<String> homeActivitiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> homeActivitiesSubList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

These are going to be uses on *every reference* of `SimpleRecyclerAdapter`.  To top it off, they're being populated every single time a `SimpleRecyclerAdapter` object is created which is obviously happening here.

I have no idea why the developer chose to do this.  If it's for efficiency reasons, then in the constructor of the `SimpleRecyclerAdapter`, you need a check in place to prevent populating the lists once they're created.  Something like this:

```
        public static List<String> homeActivitiesList = null;
        public static List<String> homeActivitiesSubList = null;
        Context context;
        OnItemClickListener clickListener;

        public SimpleRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
            isHomeList = true;
            this.context = context;
            setHomeActivitiesList(context);
        }

        public void setHomeActivitiesList(Context context) {
            if (homeActivitiesList == null) {
              homeActivitiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
              homeActivitiesSubList = new ArrayList<String();
              String[] listArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home_activities);
              String[] subTitleArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home_activities_subtitle);
              for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length; ++i) {
                homeActivitiesList.add(listArray[i]);
                homeActivitiesSubList.add(subTitleArray[i]);
              }
           }
        }
```

Another thing to do is to make sure you're not creating a new Fragment every time you replace.  So in your Main Activity, you can keep a reference to your HomeFragment, and use that instead of creating a new one like so:

```
HomeFragment mHomeFragment = null

public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment myFragment = null;
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
            if (mHomeFragment == null) {
                mHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            }
            myFragment = mHomeFragment;
            break;
        case 1:
            //myFragment = new TestFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            // TODO: Add more
            break;

    }
    if(myFragment!=null)
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, myFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

This way, you can ensure that all the contents of the last HomeFragment remain in memory as long as MainActivity exists in memory.

Comment: Ah, so the combination of the static list and the constant repopulation on the creation of `SimpleRecyclerAdapter`, in addition to a mistake on my part led to the constant duplication.

... I spent a good couple of hours unable to figure that out. Thank you so much for spending the time to assist me. You deserve a hug. And a cookie.

Have a nice day!